# Size of named pipe? Process gets stuck

Tags: c, linux, fifo

How can I find out how many bytes are in a named pipe?

I want to check if there is still enough space before inserting a new object. At the moment my sending process gets stuck if the receiving process is to slow in taking the objects out of the pipe or if it is crashed.

My code looks like:

```
/*We open the fifo for read and write*/
  if((fd_fifo=open(fifo_name, O_RDWR)) == - 1)
    {
       snprintf (retval, strlen(retval), "Can't open the fifo: %s", fifo_name);
      *length = strlen(retval);
      return retval;
    }

//  write(fd_fifo,puffer,strlen(puffer)) ;

  int wbytes = write(fd_fifo,messagebody,strlen(messagebody)) ;

  if (wbytes == -1)
    {
       snprintf (retval, strlen(retval), "Can't write to fifo: %s", fifo_name);
      *length = strlen(retval);
      return retval;
    }
```

Comment: `I want to check if there is still enough space before inserting a new object`. You can choose a different approach. **`O_NONBLOCK`** is the option you can use for the pipe and your code will not get stuck: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, blocking occurs on a named pipe, when you use `write` or `read` system calls. So, if the pipe is opened for reading, the process will block until some other process opens it for writing and vice-versa. If this behavior is undesirable, the `O_NONBLOCK` flag can be used in an `open()` call to disable the default blocking action.

If you wish to know when a pipe is ready to read/write, you should look into `man 2 select` and `man 2 poll` commands, which notify such events.

If you use blocking calls, you can also use the `FIONREAD` in an `ioctl` call:

```
 rc = ioctl(pipefd, FIONREAD, &nBytesAvailable);
```

Note that `ioctl()` calls behaviors are implementation defined and you should check your system's man pages(`man 2 ioctl`) to get more accurate idea.